# why the first string is printed repeatly irrespective of number of test cases and how to correct it. Please correct it. language is c used

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    int i, j, t;
    scanf("%d", &t); // enter the number of test cases 
    getchar();
    char input[11111];
    for(i=0; i<t; i++){
        scanf("%[^STOP]", input); // take input till STOP will come
        printf("%s\n", input); 
// this code print first input as many time as number of test cases in the code that will we provide through variable t;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have run the code and I got output as,
Input section
     5
     A
     B
     C
     D
     E
     F
     G
     STOP
output section
A
B
C
D
E
F
G

A
B
C
D
E
F
G

A
B
C
D
E
F
G

A
B
C
D
E
F
G

A
B
C
D
E
F
G

please correct it as your expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    int i, j, t;
    char ch;
    scanf("%d", &t); // enter the number of test cases 
    getchar();
    char input[11111];
    for(i=0; i<t; i++){
        scanf("%[^STOP]", input); // take input till STOP will come
        while((ch=getchar())!='\n'&& ch!= EOF);
        printf("%s\n", input); 
// this code print first input as many time as number of test cases in the code that will we provide through variable t;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem was caused because of buffering. `scanf()` sends `\n` to the input buffer and the next `scanf()` reads this. That is what caused the problems.

If you want to know more about this, just search for input buffer in Stack Overflow or in Google. This problem has been discussed over and over many times.